# Understanding OpenID message flow

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

Being new to OpenID, I have read the v2.0 spec and sketched out what I think happens in a fairly simple auth case. I then downloaded the DotNetOpenAuth samples and using these and various web searches have tried to understand the samples and the process flow better but I'm struggling.
I am trying to write an OpenID provider but it is hard to learn each step since DotNetOpenAuth has too little documentation that I can find and the various tutorials around are either too brief, too old (v1) or too confusing.
I thought of decrypting the conversation with google on an OpenID site but somehow google manages to prevent Fiddler from decrypting its ssl traffic.
Can anyone point me at a technical but clear tutorial/introduction/guide to writing an OpenID provider, preferably using the DotnetOpenAuth library? I think I'm nearly there!
TIA

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/) and/or [this](http://blog.techcle.com/2010/03/20/simple-oauth-integration-for-twitter-in-asp-net-mvc/) can help you.

Edit: also found [this example](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx).

I am also struggling to understand and find much useful material for `dotnetopenauth`.